# Access to k3s DNS from host

Tags: kubernetes, dns, minikube

I have a single node k3s "cluster" with few `Service`s on it.

Whenever I want to access to one of them, I'm forced to either do a `port-forward` or a `describe` (and get the endpoint, but it changes each time).
From what I have read, `ingress` (with a local `nginx` `ingress controller`) suffers from the same issue.

Isn't there a way to reliably (ie. resisting to reload/reboot), plug my host machine DNS resolution on k3s DNS?

Comment: K3s comes with built-in traefik ingress listening on host's ports 80 and 443. A simple ingress resource should expose your service on this port with configuration of your choosing defined in ingress - see here my tutorial on unrelated matter, but it has a part for Jenkins installation with a sample how I'm exposing Jenkins via Ingress - https://worklifenotes.com/2022/01/04/jenkins-builds-with-kaniko-and-reliza-tutorial/

Comment: I'm using NixOS and these ports aren't exposed (even without firewalls)

Comment: Then it's something specific for NixOS and not for K3s per se. I'm not an expert there, if they have any community support I would ask there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, I should have searched more: [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) is what I want, letting me expose ports on my local machine.

Comment: While this may be fine for a local dev environment, in general using NodePorts is very rarely warranted. What may be recommended instead is a proper ingress configuration. Also, core issue in this question seems to be compatibility problem between NixOS and K3s which is not addressed by this answer.